# How to by pass SQL native error for duplicate records?

Tags: sql, db2, windev

I am getting this error when  a program executing, when it is trying to update data in the table. Is this because of duplicate record ? what will be the condition to avoid sql error for duplicate record. below error:

Description = [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0803N  One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1" constrains table "FH.Product" from having duplicate values for the index key.  SQLSTATE=23505
Code here:

```
 request = [
    UPDATE FH.product
    SET numchassis='%3',mtoc='%4'
    WHERE numchassis='%1' AND mtoc='%2'
]      
query=Constructed String(query,sChassis,sMTOC,sVin,sNewMTOC)
SQLChangeConnection(nCnx_DWH)
bRes = SQLExec(query,"REQUPD3")
IF NOT bRes THEN
    SQLInfoGene("REQUPD3")
    gsError=SQL. MyError+RC+Request
    sSQLState is a string = SQL. MyError
    sNativeErrorCode is a string = Spaceless(ExtractString(sSQLState,2,"Native Error Code ="))
    sSQLState = WithoutSpace(ExtractString(ExtractString(sSQLState,2,"SQL State ="),1,RC))
    //If update error because duplicate
    IF sNativeErrorCode = "-803" AND sSQLState = "23505" THEN
        Delete
        ECRIRE_TRACE("calling If condition ")
        deleteDepot(sChassis,sMTOC)
    OTHERWISE
        FIN_ERREUR()
    END
END
```

Problem is in IF condition, it is not calling the deleteDepot()method.

Comment: I used this condition:  if (sNativeErrorCode = "-803" && sSQLState = "23505") {
 deleteData(vin,mtoc);
}
else {System.out.println("sql error");
after matching the if condition also the control not going to the deleteData() method.
what to put in the if condition so it will call the deleteData() method.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: Are you asking if this means there would be duplicates in the table or how to avoid it based on SQL statements or how to handle it in what seems Javascript / Node.js? Add more details to the question by editing it.

Comment: I am asking. how to handle it, If we have duplicate record while executing the sql query. Through the program . basically I tried this way but it is not entering into the if condition example: if (sNativeErrorCode = "-803" && sSQLState = "23505").

Comment: [SQL0803N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0750-sql0999#sql0803n). What's the programming language and data types of `sNativeErrorCode` & `sSQLState`?

Comment: Please add every detail to the question itself by editing it. And format the code and messages for readability

Comment: Programming language we used as  windev which is internally used H -language. sNativeErrorCode & sSQLState are string.

Comment: You don't have to test both sqlcode and sqlstate, just test sqlstate, I think the code should be `IF SQL.Error = "23505" THEN`

Comment: Hi,  I used sSQLState = "23505". and it is working. Thank you very much for help.